# What are those "gke-xxxx" users in my GCE instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I found users like gke-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx in /etc/passwd in all my GCE instances.
I never defined these users as a project owner.
What is it? Is it dangerous?

Comment: I took the liberty to reformulate your question so that it's easier to find for users with the same doubt.

Answer (score 1):

These users in your GCE VMs are a side effect of the creation of GKE clusters in your project.

GKE currently uses [SSH Tunnels](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/control-plane-node-communication/#ssh-tunnels) for control plane to node communication. They allow the GKE master(s), located in a Google-owned project, to communicate with the GKE nodes located in your project. To enable this, SSH keys are created at your project level, which, as a side effect, creates corresponding user in all your project's VMs. This will change in later GKE versions with the implementation of the [Konnectivity service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/control-plane-node-communication/#konnectivity-service).

Note that when you delete a GKE cluster in your project, the corresponding SSH key is deleted from your project metadata but corresponding user in your existing VMs isn't deleted. Consequently you may see *gke-xxxx* users in your VMs even if you don't have a GKE cluster anymore in your project. In this case you can safely remove these users from your VMs.